# The url is changing but the component is not rendered correctly?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am having a problem, I am using react router and I will explain the situation.

I have a form to log in, with /authenticate in the url, if authentication is successed then I go to "/" ( home page ) which is doing good now, and I have two navigation bars, one on the left, the other on the top, now when I click on the links, the url changes but the components are not rendered on clicking them, but if I tap the url on the browser and click enter ( page refreshed ) the component is rendered correctly.

Here is my code :

This is the component rendered after the succesful log in, it is my main application, so The MenuGauche and MenuTop are always rendered :

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import MenuGauche from "./MenuGauche";
import MenuTop from "./MenuTop";
import Acceuil from "./Acceuil";
import Roles from "./Roles";

const Application = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MenuGauche></MenuGauche>
      <MenuTop></MenuTop>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Acceuil}></Route>
          <Route path="/roles" component={Roles}></Route>
       </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Application;
```

And here is my top route component ( the default component suggested by react ) :

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <I18nProvider locale={props.language.language}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Application}></Route>
            <Route path="/authenticate" component={Authentification}></Route>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </I18nProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Why is that not working ? I would like to get any help to solve that, a solution or a proposition!

One solution is provided, it is that  have to keep the BrowserRouter only in the top root component, but still nothing!

here is the modification :

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import MenuGauche from "./MenuGauche";
import MenuTop from "./MenuTop";
import Acceuil from "./Acceuil";
import Roles from "./Roles";

const Application = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MenuGauche></MenuGauche>
      <MenuTop></MenuTop>

          <Route path="/" component={Acceuil}></Route>
          <Route path="/roles" component={Roles}></Route>

    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Application;
```

If you feel like I need to provide more code just ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are using two `BrowserRouter` component, make sure that is is used once and it is in most top level component in whole application

Comment: I did remove it from the Application component and kep it only in the App component, still having the same problem